# To get values from custom control

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the below code I have user controls like textbox, dropdown, checkbox, etc. and I bind it to a datalist. Now I have refer the controls to .aspx web page now my aim is to get the values of custom controls in .aspx page. Please help me to do this. My aim is to get the values of textbox, dropdown, checkbox from `usercontrols` in .aspx.

**GmatField.ascx**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtField" runat="server" width="200Px" CssClass="style22"  ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:DropDownList ID="cbField" runat="server" width="200Px" >
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chField" runat="server" width="200Px"  />
```

**GmatField.ascx**

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="gmat" TagName="FieldCont" Src="~/Search/GmatField.ascx" %>

<asp:DataList ID="dlFields" runat="server"  Height="100px" 
    Width="50px" BorderColor="Beige">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <gmat:FieldCont ID="gmatFieldCont" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

**NewDocument.aspx**

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="gmat" TagName="GmatFieldsControl" Src="~/Search/GmatFields.ascx" %>
    <gmat:GmatFieldsControl ID="gmatFieldsContr" runat="server" />
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what you want my friend .. please explain more

Comment: I have no idea what you said.

Comment: @ Karim AG I have controls like textbox,dropdown,checkbox in GmatField.ascx.Now i want to get that values in NewDocument.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Simple.

Create a public property that gets the value from the textbox or selectedItem dropdownlist
Then from the page that implements that user control, you can then access the property:

```
// usercontrol:
public string TxtField
{
   get 
   {
      return this.txtField.Text;
   }
}

// from the ASPX page that implements the usercontrol:

string txtFieldValue = this.gmatFieldsContr.TxtField;
```

Comment: It shows are you missing any directive in this.gmatFieldsContr.TxtField;

Comment: make sure you are referencing the CORRECT name of the user control. This is on the idea/description you gave that the usercontrol is on the same page you are trying to reference.